# Error with Unity Framework in .NET WPF

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, unity-container

I am getting following error while compiling my project. I am using unity framework for dependency injection with unity framework version 3.0.0.0 with visual studio 4.5. As far as I understand its demanding unity version 3.0.1208.

If this is the case, from where I can download this version, as I found nothing about it on google.

```
Assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.1208.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   e:\DataForm\Binaries\PRISM\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll    DataForm.WPFApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem I have to do this:

1)"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\ildasm.exe" Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll /out:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.il

2) Edit the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.il Line 21 to: ".ver 3:0:1208:0"->".ver 3:0:0:0"

3) save the .il file

4)"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe" Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.il /dll /out:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll

Use the new .dll which has a reference to the version 3.0.0 and not 3.0.1208..

Hope it help ;)

### Update:

Probably you will also need to do a new sign on the new assembly:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\ildasm.exe" Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll /out:.\Signed\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.il

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe" .\Signed\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.il /dll /key="C:\MyPublicPrivateKeyFile.snk"  /output=.\Signed\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll